# Export Vertica query result to csv file

Tags: sql, csv, export, vertica

I`m working with Vertica. I try to export data from SELECT query into csv. I tried making it with sql query:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/fileName.csv' FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
```

I got an error:

```
[Vertica][VJDBC](4856) ERROR: Syntax error at or near "INTO"
```

Is there a way to export a query result to a csv file? I prefer not to use vsql, but if there no other way, I will use it. I tried the following:

```
vsql -c "select * from table_name;" > /tmp/export_data.txt
```

Answer (score 12):

Here is how you do it:

```
vsql -U dbadmin -F ',' -A -P footer=off -o dumpfile.txt -c "select ... from ... where ...;"
```

Reference: [Exporting Data Using vsql](https://my.vertica.com/docs/9.0.x/HTML/index.htm#Authoring/ConnectingToVertica/vsql/ExportingDataUsingVsql.htm)

Comment: ```vsql -U dbadmin dwh -A -P footer=off -F ',' -c "SELECT 'Definitely not a valid csv, but who cares, right?' AS mycolumn;"  |  RESULT: |
mycolumn
Definitely not a valid csv, but who cares, right?
```

Comment: How do I provide quote charater here.  For example my output should be -> a,"hi,there",1

Answer (score 6):

Accordingly to https://my.vertica.com/docs/7.1.x/HTML/Content/Authoring/ConnectingToHPVertica/vsql/ExportingDataUsingVsql.htm

```
=> SELECT * FROM my_table;
 a |   b   | c
---+-------+---
 a | one   | 1
 b | two   | 2
 c | three | 3
 d | four  | 4
 e | five  | 5
(5 rows)
=> \a
Output format is unaligned.
=> \t
Showing only tuples.
=> \pset fieldsep ','
Field separator is ",".
=> \o dumpfile.txt
=> select * from my_table;
=> \o
=> \! cat dumpfile.txt
a,one,1
b,two,2
c,three,3
d,four,4
e,five,5
```

Comment: Thanks for it. I think `=> \pset fieldsep '\t'` will be `=> \pset fieldsep ','` (according to response)

Comment: Does not handle case when data contains separator.

Answer (score 3):

By following way you can write to CSV file as comma separated and no footer.

```
vsql -h $HOST -U $USER -d $DATABASE -w $PASSWORD -f $SQL_PATH/SQL_FILE -A -o $FILE -F ',' -P footer=off  -q
```

Comment: +1 for footer=off, also - meta-command "-t --tuples-only disables printing of column names, result row count footers, and so on"

Comment: Considering `-o` is used, `-q` seems unnecessary.

Comment: Does not handle case when data contains separator.